# How to make free trial period for user in django after sign up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've implemented subscription payments to my django app using [dj-paddle](https://github.com/paddle-python/dj-paddle). The only problem is if a user wants to start a free trial, they have to enter their credit card details.There's no option to disable credit card requirement on paddle.

I want to handle free trials outside of paddle locally so users don't have to enter their credit card to try out the app.

How do i assign a custom role to a user automatically after registering for example 'free_trial'  that switches to another custom role 'trial_expired' after 7 days?

This way i can just call the method in my templates e.g

```
 {% if user.free_trial %}
        #Access to app
        {% else %}
         "Your trial has expired"
        {% endif %}
```

user views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created {username}!')
            new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                                    password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                                    )
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')

    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

This is how i've currently implemented dj-paddle to restrict access to non subscribers in my app.

User model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    
    
    def has_subscription(self):
        return self.subscriptions.filter(Q(status='active') | Q(status='trialing')).exists()
```

My templates

```
  {% if user.has_subscription %}
    #Access to app"
    {% else %}
     #Render Payment form"
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new boolean field in my model for example:

```
free_trial = models.BooleanField(default=True)
registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Upon creation free_trial would be automatically enabled. Next you need to set a scheduled task(such as Celery) to each each day/hour or certain time frame to execute a script such as:

```
for user in User.objects.filter(free_trial=True):
    user.check_trial_expired()
```

And add check_trial_expired() function to your user model which would check if seven days has passed and would modify the free_trial = False

I would recommend to configure the trial as optional and add another field such as trial_start_date and other options if needed. That way customers would be able to start a trial when they want to which is the recommended way. Also, you would be able to "gift" additional free trials for "unhappy" customers or similar.